# Minecraft melee mobs don't attack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing a lot of Minecraft Demo recently, and one thing I have noticed is that melee mobs like Zombies, Vindicators or Endermen refuse to attack me, even if I attack them first. I did modify the world data to give myself hardcore mode and extend the trial time, but that's all I did. Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that I was setting the time value to a negative number, which makes mobs not attack.