# Is editing level.dat illegal

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’m playing the Minecraft demo and I want to give myself more time. I wish to edit level.dat to achieve that goal, but I don’t know if it goes against the EULA.

Comment: According to [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387922/minecraft-melee-mobs-dont-attack) you've already given yourself more time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, per the tag wiki of the [tag:legal] tag, "Questions asking if something is (il)legal are off topic here"

Answer (score 2):

Illegal according to what?

There is nothing criminal with regards to you editing code that's on your computer in this situation. The EULA is an agreement between you and the company. Breaking it means they can ban your account (but they can ban your account for no reason anyways). There won't be any criminal liabilities unless you sell your modification and/or services to perform this.

In addition, you are fully liable for your modifications. If your code edits somehow causes collateral damage, whatever that may be, you become fully liable for your modification.

Answer (score -3):

Basically yes, but noone cares if you do.

Comment: Do you have any source(s) to back this up?

Comment: Someone has left a comment saying that, but I can't find it now.

Comment: it's a file on your computer.  there's nothing illegal about it.

Comment: @Millard That's oversimplifying things.

Comment: @Joachim I minsinterpreted NotVeryGoodAtThis question, I thought he was altering the amount of time in game to complete an objective or something, I didn't realize he was altering his free trial (correct me if I'm wrong), in which case, it could possibly be illegal, but I don't really know.  srry I wasn't helpful, =)

Comment: @Millard That's okay :)